# Reference Error on Index Page with Twitter Cards EJS

Tags: node.js, twitter, ejs

I have the following code in my header.ejs file for my Twitter card.

```
<head>
...
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@DrDenverHBubble">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@DrDenverHBubble">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<%= blog.title %>"></meta>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<%= blog.image %>"></meta>
</head>
...
```

On my show.ejs page, my webpage display correctly and the Twitter card displays correctly as well on Twitter.

However, on my index.ejs page, I get the following error with the below code

```
ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/drdenver/views/blogs/index.ejs:1
 >> 1| <% include ../partials/header %>
    2|   
    3| 
    4| 

/home/ubuntu/workspace/drdenver/views/partials/header.ejs:16
    14| <meta name="twitter:site" content="@DrDenverHBubble">
    15| <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@DrDenverHBubble">
 >> 16| <meta name="twitter:title" content="<%= blog.title %>"></meta>
    17| <meta name="twitter:image" content="<%= blog.image %>"></meta>
    18|     </head>
    19|     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

blog is not defined
```

Here is the index.ejs code

```
<% include ../partials/header %>



<div id="blog-index" class="container">
<div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <% if(noMatch !== null) { %>
      <h4> <%= noMatch %> </h4>
    <% } %>
  </div>
  <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ui medium rounded items">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="<%= blog.image %>">
          </div>
        <div class="content">
          <a class="header" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%=blog.title%></a>
          <div class="meta">
          <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
          </div>

          <div class="extra">
            <% if(blog.body && blog.body.length > 0) { %>
            <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 120) %> ... </p>
            <% } %>
            <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">Read More</a>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  <% }) %>
</div>
...
```

I am a new coder, but I understand that I am not passing anything into the variable blog which is causing my error. My solution was to on the show page remove the <% include ../partials/header %> and insert the header code with twitter card code and in the header.ejs page remove the Twitter card code. Is there a more DRY way of coding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, You are including header.ejs file which needs blog data. But you are not passing blog data to it. Change your include line to following

```
<%- include('../partials/header', {blog: blog}); %>
```

Comment: Hi Karthikdiv, I tried the code in to what you suggested and I am getting this the same error this time on the the new code line `ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/drdenver/views/blogs/index.ejs:1
 >> 1| <%- include('../partials/header', {blog: blog}); %>
    2|   
    3| 
    4| 

blog is not defined`

Comment: Are you sending blog object to index.ejs?

Comment: I changed my first block of code from `<% include ../partials/header %>` to `<%- include('../partials/header', {blog: blog}); %>`